# Preprocess multivalues feature?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

How to preprocess multivalued feature (genre_ids)?

As I need to assign one numeric value to each row of one column, but how efficiently I can preprocess this genre_ids?

```
msno  |city |bd  |gender| song_id| song_length| genre_ids| artist_name 
1      12   33    0       11       222          372                89   
2      11   23    1       1        202          372|374|375        99
3      14   22    1       2        300          386                78
```

Comment: SO one way war to construct a column for each genre_id and encoding it as a sparsematrix maybe (One_Hot_encoding). However, to condense this huge matrix, you could try to use some unsupervised learning methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package to solve your task:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'msno': [1, 2, 3],
                   'city': [12, 11, 14],
                   'bd': [33, 23, 22],
                   'gender': [0, 1, 1],
                   'song_id': [11, 1, 2],
                   'song_length': [222, 202, 300],
                   'genre_ids': ['372', '372|374|375', '386'],
                   'artist_name': [89, 99, 78]})

genre_ids_dummies = (pd.get_dummies(df.genre_ids.apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))
                                                .apply(pd.Series)
                                                .stack()).sum(level=0))
df_processed = pd.concat(objs=[df.drop(labels='genre_ids', axis=1), 
                               genre_ids_dummies], axis=1)
```